# heroku moment() js unix timestamp is incorrect

Tags: heroku, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I have an issue on a Heroku server. Saving a unix timestamp to my DB using moment.js on my local server functions correctly. However on Heroku the timestamp is 23 hours behind, rounded down to the nearest hour.

```
dateProvided = Number(moment($('#dateProvided').val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY').unix())
```

The value provided by $('#dateProvided').val() is "12/08/2017". The unix timestamp for both the local and Heroku server is "1502492400" which is "08/11/2017 @ 11:00pm (UTC)" when converting.

**Return value**

When I want the value that has been saved the code is:

```
moment.unix(dateProvided).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

**Browser**

The code above returns the correct date "12/08/2017" on the browser.

**Heroku server**

The code above returns the incorrect date "11/08/2017" on the Heroku server.

Comment: As stated [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/): _By default, moment parses and displays in local time._, so your `$('#dateProvided').val()` will be interpreted as _local time_ (time of the environment where the code is executed), maybe this behaviour is causing your issue.

Comment: The value being returned by $('#dateProvided').val() is "12/08/2017" so this looks ok. Heroku is set to UTC by default. It's like moment thinks I'm in a timezone in Asia or something.

Comment: What is the value returned by `moment($('#dateProvided').val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY').unix()`? Where this code is executed (browser/node)? Which is your expected result?

Comment: @VincenzoC thanks for you responses, I'll edit the question.

Comment: The key is saving the unix timestamp the same as the date that's provided i.e. "12/08/2017" as the servers not going to know the clients local timezone unless I pass that timezone as data which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my local timezone was being used as the unix timestamp and Heroku is on UTC timezone. Therefore when saving Heroku was differing. The solution is:

```
moment.utc(value, 'DD/MM/YYYY').unix()
```

This ensures the timezone is the same as Heroku when saving a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Use the module **moment-timezone** as this handles all types of timezones around the world. It fixed my problem with Heroku date/times.

```
Example: 
const date = moment().tz('Europe/London').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Further info: https://momentjs.com/timezone/